# Jenkins loads data from json file as choices of parameter does not work properly

Tags: jenkins, json

I am completely novice at Jenkins,
this post [Jenkins Plugin:Extended Choice Parameter from JSON file](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/jenkins-pluginextended-choice-parameter-from-json-file)
does work for me.

I want to load a list of versions from a json file, which name is **input.json**,
and use this version list as choices of one parameter, named **version_list**.
The input.json file is in my **$WORKSPACE**, it's content is :

```
{
    "versions":["V1","V2"]
}
```

The pipeline script is as follows:

```
pipeline {
agent any


    stages {
        
        stage("load json") {
            steps {
                echo "version_list = ${params.version_list}"
            }
        }
        stage("open_json") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def prop = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/input.json"
                    def version_list = prop.versions
    
                    println version_list.join(',')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter **version_list**  is setted as follows:

- Extended Choice Paramter
- name: versioin_list
- Parameter Type: Check Boxes
- Choose Source for Value: Groovy Script, and it's content is:

```
def prop = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/input.json"
def version_list = prop.versions
return version_list.join(',')
```

When I build this job, there is nothing to choice for parameter version_list,
but the output shows it can read data from input.json, this is one output:

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /home/hdl/.jenkins/workspace/json_as_parameter
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (load json)
[Pipeline] echo
version_list = null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (open_json)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
"V1","V2"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The load json stage can not get the value of ${params.version_list}
but the open_json stage can load json properly.

If is replace groovy script of versison_list simpley as follows:

```
def version_list = ["V1","V2"]
return version_list.join(',')
```

It works well.

I don't know why.
Any help, thanks!